# What text editor for a java programmer?

Tags: java

I'm looking for a text editor, does anyone have any recommendations? I won't be using it to program/compile/debug, Eclipse already handles all that perfectly. Its really going to be used for viewing source and occasionally writing/editing other files (eg SQL, simple HTML, JavaScript etc).

Requirements;

- Runs on Windows XP
- Free
- Lightweight (I don't want to wait 10s for it to load all its features, I just want to see the contents of the file and I want to see them *right now*)
- Syntax highlighting (for all the common file types, eg .java .sql .html .xml etc)
- Tabs
- No adverts/annoying 'donate to stop this message'

It would be nice to have an auto-format option with configurable style/format preferences, but this is not necessary.

I've tried the following;

- Textpad (isn't free)
- EditPadPro (isn't free)
- JEdit (too big a footprint, takes too long to load)

I'm trying Notepad++ but would welcome your experience.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, seems like Notepad++ is popular with a lot of people, I'll see how I get on with it.

Comment: I don't like Notepad++ that much, it feels and looks like it has been designed by a programmer. I suppose that's why so many programmers like it. But it is still the best free editor I know. I recently chose to buy EditPad Pro.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Notepad++ should be the right one.
Also try Emacs, it doesn't look native though (because when your code grows, regex based find would come handy, where Notepad++ doesn't do very well).

Comment: Emacs is anything but lightweight.

Comment: Notepad++ is the best free text editor that I have found.

Comment: +100000000 for Notepad++

Comment: +1 Emacs should be good. Also can have a look at XEmacs http://www.xemacs.org/

Comment: I added Emacs because I had trouble with regex based searching in Notepad++, for which I used Emacs.

Comment: Every other day I find another useful feature of Notepad++

Answer (score 6):

I really like [PSPad](http://www.pspad.com/en/) on Windows.

Answer (score 4):

I quite like [Programmers Notepad](http://www.pnotepad.org/), should cover everything you want.

Comment: Do you mean programmer's editor, http://download.cnet.com/Programmer-s-File-Editor-32-bit/3640-2352_4-904159.html ?

Comment: No, Programmers Notepad (as edited by 0xA3) - see the link

Answer (score 3):

I've been using various "simple" text editors until I saw the light and started using [Vim](http://www.vim.org/).

It takes some getting used to, but it's worth the effort.

Answer (score 2):

[UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com)

Comment: For me, UltraEdit is well and truly worth paying for. I use it every day at home and work as a general purpose editor and customise it heavily with macros, scripts and templates to handle many repetitive tasks. Personally, I rarely use it for Java work though: no text editor comes close to an IDE like Eclipse for Java programming work.

Answer (score 2):

gVIM can be also a good option. Also for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Editplus

Comment: I don't like Editplus too much. But that's just my opinion. I think all who use(and buy) Editplus haven't experienced Notepad++ in their life.

Answer (score 1):

See if you can manage to install [Kate](http://kate-editor.org/) on Windows. Of course its possible. :)

Okay!! here you go, [windows.kde.org](http://windows.kde.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find a link to EditPlus version 2.21. It looks like the trial is limited but it's not. Been using it for years and I've found it's a lot better then ultra edit and all the lookalikes.

Answer (score 0):

NotePad Plus has some serious problems.  Go To Line Number rarely works.  Searching for text in a file didn't work for me either.  JEdit Find In Files results are not presented well. EditPlus is not free.  It still seems to me that TextPad is the best by far.  Free for personal use.  I once had an employer pay for a copy and I paid for a copy myself.  Definitely worth it

OK, I just found the best one.  Programmer's Notepad.  Very good set of featuers and excellent color options for different source code elements.

http://www.pnotepad.org/

It passed all of my tests.

Eclipse may be OK as an editor but it is very buggy.  If you are using it for development you will run into frustating problems.  I have NOT found it to increase my productivity.

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text is amazing. It does occasionally show a message for donation/payment but even with heavy usage, it is tolerable and rarely pops up. So I don't think it's an issue. It's free and and almost a perfect text editor and you're unlikely to ever complain about anything. Using it for 4-5 years already.